# How can I show the last row of multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, select

When printing labels, I am saving the label to the database one by one. When listing, I want to show only the last data according to date and number, how can I do it?

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    lp.*, brc.BarcodeName, pr.PrinterName 
FROM 
    tbl_LabelPrint lp 
JOIN 
    tbl_Barcode brc ON lp.ProductNo = brc.ProductNo 
JOIN  
    tbl_Printer pr ON lp.IP = pr.IP 
WHERE  
    Date BETWEEN @Day AND @Day2 
ORDER BY 
    lp.SerialNo DESC
```

Output:

[image]

UPDATE=>
I was trying to get the last data for multiple kinds of data,i got it done with this query

```
SELECT *,b.BarcodeName,p.PrinterName FROM (SELECT ProductNo,Number, IP,ToUser,FromUser,Time,Date,COUNT(*) as sayi from tbl_LabelPrint group by  ProductNo,Number,IP,ToUser,FromUser,Time,Date HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) tbl JOIN tbl_Printer P ON P.IP =tbl.IP JOIN tbl_Barcode b ON b.ProductNo =tbl.ProductNo WHERE Date Between @Day and @Day2
```

Comment: Reverse the order and select the first row only: `SELECT TOP 1 .... ORDER BY ThatDate Desc, ThatNumber Desc`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tbl_LabelPrint 
ORDER BY LabelPrintId DESC
```

If you want always to get the last label you put in just use your Primary key (Im Assuming that's LablePritId) and Order by descending.